# Spark DF schema works successfully for single field, then throws error when another field is added

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I create a schema with only the first field, spark sql proceeds without issue, but if I uncomment any additional fields (i.e. I've uncommented `s_store_id` below) in both the `mapper` and the `schema`, I get a type error saying that the integer designation was not expecting a string.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
import pyspark.sql.types as types
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import *

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

#sample raw data for this table
data = [
'1|AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA|1997-03-13||2451189|ought|245|5250760|8AM-4PM|William Ward|2|Unknown|Enough high areas stop expectations. Elaborate, local is|Charles Bartley|1|Unknown|1|Unknown|767|Spring |Wy|Suite 250|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.03|',
'2|AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA|1997-03-13|2000-03-12||able|236|5285950|8AM-4PM|Scott Smith|8|Unknown|Parliamentary candidates wait then heavy, keen mil|David Lamontagne|1|Unknown|1|Unknown|255|Sycamore |Dr.|Suite 410|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|UnitedStates|-5|0.03|',
'3|AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA|2000-03-13|||able|236|7557959|8AM-4PM|Scott Smith|7|Unknown|Impossible, true arms can treat constant, complete w|David Lamontagne|1|Unknown|1|Unknown|877|Park Laurel|Road|Suite T|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.03|',
'4|AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA|1997-03-13|1999-03-13|2451044|ese|218|9341467|8AM-4PM|Edwin Adams|4|Unknown|Events would achieve other, eastern hours. Mechanisms must not eat other, new org|Thomas Pollack|1|Unknown|1|Unknown|27|Lake |Ln|Suite 260|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.03|',
'5|AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA|1999-03-14|2001-03-12|2450910|anti|288|9078805|8AM-4PM|Edwin Adams|8|Unknown|Events would achieve other, eastern hours. Mechanisms must not eat other, new org|Thomas Pollack|1|Unknown|1|Unknown|27|Lee 6th|Court|Suite 80|Fairview|Williamson County|TN|35709|United States|-5|0.03|'
]

# Import the above sample data into RDD
lines = sc.parallelize(data)

# map the data, return data as a Row, and cast data types of some fields

def mapper(lines):
    r = lines.split("|")
    return Row(
        s_store_sk=int(r[0]),
        s_store_id=r[1],
        # s_rec_start_date=None if r[2]=='' else datetime.strptime(r[2],'%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        # s_rec_end_date=None if r[3]=='' else datetime.strptime(r[3],'%Y-%m-%d').date(),
        # s_closed_date_sk=None if r[4]=='' else int(r[4]),
        # s_store_name=r[5],
        # s_number_employees=None if r[6]=='' else int(r[6]),
        # s_floor_space=None if r[7]=='' else int(r[7]),
        # s_hours=r[8],
        # s_manager=r[9],
        # s_market_id=None if r[10]=='' else int(r[10]),
        # s_geography_class=r[11],
        # s_market_desc=r[12],
        # s_market_manager=r[13],
        # s_division_id=None if r[14]=='' else int(r[14]),
        # s_division_name=r[15],
        # s_company_id=None if r[16]=='' else int(r[16]),
        # s_company_name=r[17],
        # s_street_number=r[18],
        # s_street_name=r[19],
        # s_street_type=r[20],
        # s_suite_number=r[21],
        # s_city=r[22],
        # s_county=r[23],
        # s_state=r[24],
        # s_zip=r[25],
        # s_country=r[26],
        # s_gmt_offset=None if r[27]=='' else Decimal(r[27]),
        # s_tax_precentage=None if r[28]=='' else Decimal(r[28])
        )

#build strict schema for the table closely based on the original sql schema
schema = types.StructType([
       types.StructField('s_store_sk',types.IntegerType())
       ,types.StructField('s_store_id',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_rec_start_date',types.DateType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_rec_end_date',types.DateType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_closed_date_sk',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_store_name',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_number_employees',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_floor_space',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_hours',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_manager',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_market_id',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_geography_class',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_market_desc',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_market_manager',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_division_id',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_division_name',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_company_id',types.IntegerType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_company_name',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_street_number',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_street_name',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_street_type',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_suite_number',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_city',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_county',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_state',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_zip',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_country',types.StringType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_gmt_offset',types.DecimalType())
    #    ,types.StructField('s_tax_precentage',types.DecimalType())
    ])

rows = lines.map(mapper)

# create data frame by passing in the mapped data AND its strict schema
store = spark.createDataFrame(rows,schema)

# create temp table name of the new table
store.createOrReplaceTempView("store")

# run basic SQL query against the table
results = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM store")

# show 20 results from query
results.show()

# end the spark application
spark.stop()
```

And this throws this error:

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 505, in prepare
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1349, in _verify_type
    _verify_type(v, f.dataType, f.nullable)
  File "/tools/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1321, in _verify_type
    raise TypeError("%s can not accept object %r in type %s" % (dataType, obj, type(obj)))
TypeError: IntegerType can not accept object 'AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA' in type <type 'str'>
```

**Is there something wrong with the way I'm handling these types?**

Comment: try returning `tuple` in `mapper()`